# HANA Global Temporary tables 'Could not find table/view' error

Tags: arcgis, hana, global-temp-tables

From HANA Studio, I run

`select * from M_TEMPORARY_TABLES`
shows that user1 has global temporary table called '#SDE_LOGFILE'.
But when I try `'select * from  user1.#SDE_LOGFILE'` I get error **'SAP DBTech JDBC: [259]: invalid table name:  Could not find table/view #SDE_LOGFILES in schema user1'**

I connected as user1 and ran the selection query and got the error.  Not sure if any special permissions are needed.

Answer (score 1):

In HANA there are different types of temporary tables.
See the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20d58a5f75191014b2fe92141b7df228.html) for details.

For this question the relevant piece is that this table is a **local** temporary table (denoted by the `#` at the beginning of the table name). Those are bound to the **session** of a user; they can only be accessed by the specific user in the specific session.
The table *meta data* including its name are visible outside the session though.

In short: the error message is not due to a lack of permissions but due to the handling of local temporary tables in HANA.